# How to pass on information from one JTable to another JTable in a different class

Tags: java

I am a new user and a beginner programmer.
I am writing a program which will assign jobs to users, basically an admin chooses a JOB from a JTable, and a user from a comboBox(username and surname taken from a mySql table), and based on the selection of job and user, that specific job go to the specific chosen user and gets dispalyed in a different JTable in a different class. So far i have managed to add jobs and display user in the combobox but have no clue on how to pass this information. Every information is appreciated. I am not sure on what code i should insert here for you guys to see so please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

Create `getters` and `setters` (Alt + Ins Intellij Idea).